# How to find out all the permissions that belong to a specific server/ database role in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, role

I can separately query all the server or database level permissions, but I want to know other thing. What server role do the given permissions exactly belong to? For example I want to see all the permissions belonging to securityadmin server role, hence I'll be able to understand what privileges the role has. I want the same for database roles. Can I find this info in SQL Server system tables?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @ShekarKola. But this provide only information for the current database, I'd like to know in general

Comment: See https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/ and https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions/ ... for anything that you need to do in each database, you just build a loop...

Comment: @Eigrig i moved my advise into Answer, kindly have a look. thanks

Comment: You can't get built-in permissions of the fixed server-level roles from system views (for example `CONTROL SERVER` permission of the `sysadmin` role). You can learn about such ones from [Chart of SQL Server Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#chart-of-sql-server-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following would help:

**Server Level permissions**

1. For server role permissions 
   `sp_srvrolepermission`
2. For Logins permissions

```
select  ge.name as Grantee,
        gr.name as Grantor,
        o.name as ObjectName,
        p.permission_name,
        P.state_desc 
from sys.server_permissions as p
        left join sys.server_principals as Ge on p.grantee_principal_id = ge.principal_id
        left join sys.server_principals as Gr on p.grantor_principal_id = gr.principal_id
        left join sys.objects as o on p.major_id = o.object_id
```

**Database Level Permissions**

```
select  ge.name as Grantee,
        gr.name as Grantor,
        o.name as ObjectName,
        p.permission_name,
        state_desc
from sys.database_permissions as p
        left join sys.database_principals as Ge on p.grantee_principal_id = ge.principal_id
        left join sys.database_principals as Gr on p.grantor_principal_id = gr.principal_id
        left join sys.objects as o on p.major_id = o.object_id
go
```

Answer (score 0):

If this can help you

```
--List all permissions for a given role

SELECT DB_NAME() AS 'DBName'
      ,p.[name] AS 'PrincipalName'
      ,p.[type_desc] AS 'PrincipalType'
      ,p2.[name] AS 'GrantedBy'
      ,dbp.[permission_name]
      ,dbp.[state_desc]
      ,so.[Name] AS 'ObjectName'
      ,so.[type_desc] AS 'ObjectType'
  FROM [sys].[database_permissions] dbp LEFT JOIN [sys].[objects] so
    ON dbp.[major_id] = so.[object_id] LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p
    ON dbp.[grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id] LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p2
    ON dbp.[grantor_principal_id] = p2.[principal_id]
WHERE p.[name] = '<role_name>'
```